# Slack Bot - Python slack send markdown messages

Tags: python, markdown, bots, slack

I'm trying to send markdown messages in slack using `SlackBot` but I'm unable to find the documentation, All I got is this:

```
response = client.chat_postMessage( 
    ...:     channel='#testing-bot', 
    ...:     text="Hello world! <@USerID> \n\n - a \n-b" 
    ...:     
    ...:     )
```

I want to send MArkdown MEssages, instead of the text one
I tried:

```
    ...:     channel='#testing-bot', 
    ...:     mkdwn="Hello world! <@UNVD64N02> \n\n - a \n-b" 
    ...:     
    ...:     )
```

but  didn't work. Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to send in the channel id (it will be alpha-numeric string) in instead of channel name (#testing-bot).

**Update**:
You can also use block kit which is a UI framework for slack apps. It comes with a block kit builder which can be used for real-time view of block code. Added the references below for both.

```py
response = client.chat_postMessage(
    channel="", # channel ID
    text="",
    blocks=[
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Hello world! <@UNVD64N02> :tada: \n\n - a \n-b"
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

**Output**: 
[image: Blockkit]

**References**:

- https://api.slack.com/block-kit
- https://api.slack.com/tools/block-kit-builder

Comment: I want to send markdown message, Channel name is working fine

Comment: What is the output you are getting on using `mkdwn` ? Have you tried using block-kit ?

Comment: Great, I have also updated the answer with block kit reference. Please upvote, if it has helped.

Answer (score 1):

I see you're using python's sdk, `chat_postMessage()` API. According to the [docs](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage#arg_mrkdwn), the key `mrkdwn` takes boolean value (which is True by default).

Example: Below code will send the message as: "Hello, **World!**"

```
response = client.chat_postMessage(
    channel="random",
    text="Hello, *World!*",
    mrkdwn=True,
)
```

For more message formatting, see [Basic formatting with mrkdwn](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#basics)